# Regexp invalid character length

Tags: mysql, sql

This MySQL query works:

```
SELECT p.slug FROM products AS p
WHERE p.slug REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]'
```

but this one does not work:

```
SELECT p.slug FROM products AS p
WHERE p.slug REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9_-(]'
```

neither this one works:

```
SELECT p.slug FROM products AS p
WHERE p.slug REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9_-\(]'
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to use `\\` to escape for that special character

`SELECT p.slug FROM products AS p WHERE p.slug REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9_-\\(]'`

For reference please read **[doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax)**

> **EDIT:** use `\\` to escape any special character in your expression. like in above query `-` is special character.

Comment: actually `-` is used to specify range i don't know what you trying to do with that so i just ignored that if you go though attached link you know how to use special character so i thought no need explain or ask about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to [escape special characters (parentheses and dash)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) with a double backslash (`\\`):

```
SELECT p.slug FROM products AS p
WHERE p.slug REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\(]'
```

The dash doesn't need to be escaped at the beginning or at the end since otherwise it is interpreted as being part of a range (e.g. `a-z`):

```
'[^a-zA-Z0-9_\\(-]'
```

Comment: i am understood, minus sign need to transfer to the end. ```SELECT p.slug FROM products AS p
WHERE p.slug REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9_\\(-]' ```